# WSO2 analytic vs. IS analytic

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

Does anyone know difference between API analytics and IS analytics component?
Why those are separated components?
Or does someone accomplished to gather them?

Also it is possible to export dashboard but what to do with it when I am not able to import it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

[APIM Analytics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Analytics) comes with WSO2 API Manager. [IS Analytics](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Monitoring+WSO2+IS+Using+WSO2+Analytics) comes with WSO2 Identity Server. Both analytics solutions are built on top of WSO2 Data Analytics Server. If we take IS Analytics it will provide useful stats and analytics based on the events published through WSO2 Identity Server such as login events, session related data etc. It's the same with APIM analytics.

If you are using both WSO2 APIM and WSO2 IS you can install both analytics features on top of WSO2 DAS. You can refer the [WSO2 Documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Installing+WSO2+APIM+Analytics+Features) for more details.